The written Torah
Moses brought the Ten Commandments down from Mount Sinai but our modern Torah contains more than just that. So when was the Torah as we have it today written?

Welcome to MiYodeya Barry and thanks for this first question. I hope my edits match your intent, if not you can further [edit]. Great to have you learn with us!

We see from many places that the rest of the Torah was also given at Sinai, and/or in the desert. See for instance https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.27.34?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

אֵ֣לֶּה הַמִּצְוֺ֗ת אֲשֶׁ֨ר צִוָּ֧ה ה' אֶת־מֹשֶׁ֖ה אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י
יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל בְּהַ֖ר סִינָֽי׃
These are the commandments that Hashem
gave Moses for the Israelite people on Mount Sinai.

You can also see in many places that Moses was teaching the Torah to Israel as they went through the time of Sinai and the desert. As to when it was written down, that is more subtle. There are two opinions given in the gemara in Gittin 60a: Was it written down as it was taught (מגילה מגילה ניתנה) or written down all at once at the end (חתומה ניתנה).
